# Python - Change UTC to local time in netCDF file

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, utc, netcdf4

I'm working with ERA5 land hourly data from ECMWF, which contains climatic variables.

The general aspect of the file is:

'era5-hourly-2m_temperature_firstfourdays-january_2017.nc'

```
Dimensions:    (latitude: 184, longitude: 129, time: 96)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -81.4 -81.3 -81.2 -81.1 ... -68.8 -68.7 -68.6
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -0.1 -0.2 -0.3 -0.4 ... -18.2 -18.3 -18.4
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 ... 2017-01-04T23:00:00
Data variables:
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2020-01-09 19:38:29 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.15.0: /opt/ecmw...
```

This is a matrix of information which contains many variables and observations.

Before any previous analysis, **I want to convert UTC time to local time (UTC-5)** using Python. I googled and surfed many pages and forums but I did not find anything that answers to my question. I realized the presence of the commands in a range of posts:

*datetime*, *pytz*, *tzinfo*, *astimezone*,

and others but none of the examples considered a netCDF file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd suggest to save yourself a lot of trouble and work in UTC whenever possible.

If you *really* need a local time, `datetime` and `zoneinfo` are your way to go. By the way, the conversion has nothing to do with `netcdf`, but remember that the `netCDF4` module offers helpful functions `num2date` and `date2num` [[docs]](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html).

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+

string = '2017-01-04T23:00:00'
dt_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(string)

# note that dt_obj is naive, i.e. it has no timezone info, so let's add it:
dt_obj = dt_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(datetime.strftime(dt_obj, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z %z'))
# 2017-01-04T23:00:00 UTC +0000

# now let's shift time to another timezone:
new_timezone = ZoneInfo('US/Eastern')
dt_obj = dt_obj.astimezone(new_timezone)
print(datetime.strftime(dt_obj, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z %z'))
# 2017-01-04T18:00:00 EST -0500
```